# How to run/compile a C++ program in Nitrous.io?

Tags: c++, compilation

I am just starting to use Nitrous.IO and I can't seem to find any information on the web on how to run C++ programs you make in it. Any help on how to run a C++ app made in Nitrous would be a huge help.

Comment: Please don't modify your question to being **not** a question because you found the answer.  Instead, keep the question as it was, and then post your **own** answer to the question.  Consider: [Can I answer my own question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I don't even know what nitrous.io _is_, but what you've just described (the answer that replaced the question) is how to compile & run virtually _any_ C++ program--nothing nitrous.io specific here.

Comment: I've rolled this question back.  If you've discovered a solution (and if you did, kudos!), then please leave it as an answer.  Answering your own questions is not only allowed, but strongly encouraged in a Q&A fashion.

Answer (score 1):

All commands are to be run within the console

Step 1:

Get inside the appropriate directory using the following command:

```
cd ./folder/subfolder/etc.
```

Step 2:

Type in the following command to run a fileName.cpp program:

```
// This will make a separate file named 'fileName' 
// within the directory you are working in.
// This can now be run in the console.
g++ -o fileName fileName.cpp
```

Step 3:

Type in the following command to run your program:

```
//The output will display in the console. Enjoy!
./fileName
```

ps: [answer was there](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22871140/revisions)